# Extracting solution from driven SHM

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, differential-equations

I guess maybe I should rather ask at the math stack exchange?

I have a simple harmonic undamped oscillator driven by a cosinusoidal force: $$ \ddot{x}+\omega_o^2x=f\cos(\Omega t).$$

I've managed to find the solution with the Ansatz $$x=A\cos(\omega_ot)+Be^{i\Omega t}+Ce^{-i\Omega t}$$ to be $$x=A\cos(\omega_ot)+\frac{f}{2(\omega_o^2-\Omega^2)}e^{i\Omega t}+\frac{f}{2(\omega_o^2+\Omega^2)}e^{-i\Omega t}$$ .

How do I extract the final real solution from those two exponentials?

Comment: Why no $\sin{\omega_0t}$ term in your ansatz?

Comment: I don’t think your third term is correct. Check your math.

Comment: ah yeah, two mistakes, now it works out, thanks @G.Smith !